# Xamarin Android app automatically opening when receiving remote notification

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

UPDATE 3: RESOLVED!

problem was not connected with FirebaseService, settings or payload. Problem was in application code... Our code had such thing (inheritance from Application):

```
 ParentDroidApplication : Application
```

In that class in OnCreate method select which activity to use and Call "StartActivity". I moved this switch to MainActivity and problem was solved.

UPDATE 2:

Android Manifest (deleted service tag):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.visma.vfsmobileparentapp" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="46">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:label="Min skole" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name="Min skole">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Payload (added content_available and priority):

```
{
 "to" : "token",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Collapsing A"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Collapsing A"
 },
 "content_available": true,
 "priority": "high"
}
```

result same: app is opening automatically after remote notification :(

UPDATE:

I added intent with my main activity, default sounds and Miliseconds as int for notification number in OnMessaggeReceive method (you can see in the code below).
I tried to delete

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I didn't receive any notifications but app is still opening. it seems that Firebase is working as it should work. But application it self doing magic

I tried to downgrade Firebase to version 42.1021.1. Result is same

QUESTION

We are developing mobiles apps with Xamarin. We need notifications and we started to use Firebase Cloud messaging. All messages (notifications) are working, receiving, even updating badges in iOS, but... one problem with Android:

If app is closed (swiped from app list) and receiving remote notification it is opening automatically. I want to avoid this. Background or foreground modes are working as expecting.

My Andoroid manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="46">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:label="App" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name="App">
  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
  <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</application>
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:stopWithTask="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
</manifest>
```

My FirebaseMessagingService.cs:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        SendNotification("title", "body"); //just for testing
    }

    public void SendNotification(string title, string body)
    {
         var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity));

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        var defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);

        var style = new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.BigText(body);

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher);
        var notificationBuilder =
            new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher)
                .SetContentTitle(title)
                .SetContentText(body)
                .SetStyle(style)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(DateTime.Now.Millisecond, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

I tried change manifest values, tried simulator, device, I sent different payloads:

both notification and data:

```
{
"to" : "token",
"notification" : {
"body" : "First Notification",
"title": "Collapsing A"
},
"data" : {
"body" : "First Notification",
"title": "Collapsing A",
}
}
```

only notification:

```
{
"to" : "token",
"notification" : { 
"body" : "First Notification", 
"title": "Collapsing A" 
}
}
```

only data:

```
{
"to" : "token", 
"data" : {
"body" : "First Notification",
"title": "Collapsing A"
}
}
```

in all cases notification is receiving and opening app automatically when app is closed. How to avoid that auto opening? I need only notification. Any ideas what I can do?

nuget packages:

```
Xamaring.Firebase.Messaging - 60.1142.1
Xamarin.Firebase.Code - 60.1142.1
Xamarin.Firebase.Common - 60.1142.1
```

tested in Android 6 and Android 7 devices (Samsung)

Comment: You should not use last <service> & <action> tag in menifest as you already doing it at the top of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` pgrammatically. Try adding `"content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",` in your json object.

Comment: thanks for input - notifications are still working after suggested changes, but app is still opening automatically after remote notification

Comment: One more thing I would suggest you try putting some other activity in `SendNotification` instead of login activity. Which don't have `MainLauncher=true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define here Activity, which has to open when you tap notification.

```
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(YourActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    //sent RemoteMessage message data to your activity if you need
    //intent.PutExtra("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, GenerateRandom(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
    var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.myIcon)
            .SetContentTitle(user.Organization)
            .SetSubText(myModuleName)
            .SetContentText(BodyText)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .Build();
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    var notification = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
   //this is for sound of notification
    var mp = MediaPlayer.Create(ApplicationContext, notification);
    mp.Start();
    notificationManager.Notify(GenerateRandom(), notificationBuilder);
```

To just give unique Id to notifications so that they wont overlap

```
private int GenerateRandom()
{
    var rn = new Java.Util.Random();
    int n = 1000 - 1233 + 1;
    int i = rn.NextInt() % n;
    return 1000 + i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help. app is still opening when remote notification arrives

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the situation tells me that since you have not given the notification a pending intent it is directly opening your application:

Workaround to this problem :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainAcitivity)); //Activity you want to open
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
 var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, RandomGenerator(), intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

In case you want default sounds :

```
 Notification notify = new Notification();
 notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Sound;
 notify.Defaults = NotificationDefaults.Vibrate;
```

Using the NotificationCompat to push the notification(For backward Compatibility)

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
             .SetContentTitle(messageTitle)
             .SetContentText(messageBody)
             .SetSound(Settings.System.DefaultNotificationUri)
             .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 })
             .SetLights(Color.AliceBlue, 3000, 3000)
             .SetAutoCancel(true)
             .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Then notifying the system that a notification is thrown from your application:

```
  NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(RandomGenerator(), notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Also, Random numbers so that the notifications don't switch places when a new one is thrown :

```
private int RandomGenerator() 
{
 return new Random().Next( int.MinValue, int.MaxValue );
}
```

And for Android Oreo channel compatibility as you can see [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), you need to add the following metadata element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` within the application component:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

This default channel will be used when notification message has no specified channel, or if the channel provided has not yet been created by the app.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help. app is still opening when remote notification arrives

Comment: Can i check the changes that you have made to the file if possible update the question itself

Comment: No i want you to update your question with the changes that you have made in your firebase service